# ECG Signal Measurement using Plessey PS25201

Tags: operational-amplifier, analog, signal-processing, ecg

The above said sensor measures the change in the electric field.
Data sheet link :  [Click here](http://www.zlgmcu.com/sensor/download/pdf/PS25201_DS_EN.pdf)

When I measure the output from the sensors directly on the CRO with finger placed on the sensor; the output is a pure square wave; blame my CRO for not showing 
minor changes in between the transitions.

The typical application of this sensor is to drive them in a differential configuration with sufficient gain (Inferred from Datasheet; Absence of Application notes makes everything harder).

What I've tried is to buffer the input from the individual electrodes with the gain of 13(INA126P) and then INA with gain of 23 (AD620); the output of INA is filtered with 2nd order active LPF and HPF with cutoff of 159Hz, 0.25Hz respectively.  Attached Schematic will give you a better idea.

The above configuration saturates the op-amp (Vcc and -Vee) (R Peak in both directions)

My question is how do I get distinguishable P,Q,S,T,U peaks from these sensors?
Anybody who has used these sensors please guide what circuit to use.

I'm sampling the output at 500Hz with Arduino.
I've also tried sampling MAX1132 ADC with CC3200 Launchpad but with no luck. 
[image: Sch which gave promising output]

EDIT : I'm not using Right Leg Drive as it's a design constraint.

Comment: Out of curiosity, did you get the PS25201 EPIC sensor to work? I have a similar problem and I would love to hear about how you solved your problem.

Comment: Please email. ammar.cma@gmail.com